# Why would you use bulk insert over insert?

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between using insert and Bulk insert. I have looked for the answer on this but I cant get a straight answer.

Comment: I know you might have to read a little bit, but the documentation explains and has links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you look for the answer?

https://www.google.com.au/#q=sql+bulk+insert+vs+insert

First result has timings to back up the theory, other links are equally informative particularly some from MSDN.

There is also a bunch of helpful results from SO.

In short, Bulk insert is faster. You can use bulk insert to insert millions of rows from a csv or xml or other files in a very short time however if you only have 3 or 4 rows to insert it's quick enough to just throw it in using insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is less logging in a bulk insert.  This results in faster operation, typically.  See this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4347510a-fcb1-4050-a457-0b79c211b465/compare-bulk-insert-vs-insert?forum=transactsql